# Best way to display nested data structure in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to display some nested data structure in my silver light application.

I am using SQL server and Entityframework.

- Say I have a class ClassA which has property of collection of ClassB.
- ClassB also can contain a collection of ClassB itself (say till 5th Level).
- ClassB also contains a collection of another class ClassA.

Can anyone help me the best way to display this in silver light page?

Comment: Are you just looking for a control suggestion? Like a TreeView or a DataGrid with Grouped nesting, or what?

Comment: Yes..i am looking for control suggestion and implementation mechanism as well..the requirement is not only to display but also to add items..like user can add new control for example user can add ClassB in ClassA or Class B..ClassC in any of the ClassB...Thanks for your reply..